# Export openssl key to file

Tags: openssl, rsa, private-key, pkcs#12

I generated a private key using commend:

```
openssl genrsa -out privKey.pem
```

Now I want to export this key to file with extension .p12, so I used commend:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey privKey.pem -out key.p12 -name "MyPrivKey"
```

but when I try to run this commend via commend line, I have no results (it's running all time and doesn't stop), and when I open the file .p12 I have message:

```
Could not display 'key.p12'
Reason: Unrecognized or unsupported data.
```

Can someone explain me, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate an crt file too.

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -days 1825 -out cert.crt -keyout key.key
```

then

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey key.key -in cert.crt -out export.p12
```

if you have a CA file will be

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey key.key -in cert.crt -certfile ca.crt -out export.p12
```

Comment: Can you suggest how to do that when I want to have a 128 bits key? Because creating certificate for 128 bits privatekey return errors.

Comment: i think will be "openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:1024 -days 1825 -out cert.crt -keyout key.key" or "openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:128 -days 1825 -out cert.crt -keyout key.key" but i am not sure..

Answer (score 0):

You need a certificate as well as your private key to convert it to PKCS#12. See the manual: https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs12.html#FILE_CREATION_OPTIONS